# How to differentiate between ascii value and a number?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am asking if there is any way in C++ to differentiate between an ASCII value and a number, for example `'A'` and `65` both have value of 65, but how to differentiate between them?

Assume we want to sum up two numbers, so `sum(10,65)` should return 75, but `sum(10,'A')` should return 0. Also, keep in mind that the arguments of `sum()` should have the same type, which is `double`.

Comment: A better way to think about it is: 'A' is the glyph represented by value 65.

Comment: `'A'` is a `char` whereas `65` is an `int` actually.

Comment: This feels like an XY-Problem.  `char` is an arithmetic type, so are `int`, `double` etc.  What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve which required arithemtic types to be treated differently without specialising the `sum` function ?

Comment: As "ASCII value" **is** a number.

Answer (score 4):

Use overloaded functions. It is quite short with your conditions (returning 0 for all argument types that are not double):

```
double sum(double a, double b) { return a + b; }

template <typename A, typename B>
double sum(A a, B b) { return 0; }
```

Comment: double CHAR = 'A';
cout << CHAR; //returns 65

Comment: The data type doesn't matter in this case, 'A', and 65 have the same value, but how to differentiate between them?

Comment: @Mario you can't differentiate by value, so you have to differentiate by type. Overloads and templates can do that

Comment: @S.M. The first code doesn't work. `sum(10,65)` causes ambiguity errors

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 and later, you can make `sum()` be a template function, and then use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to let `sum()` make decisions based on the types of parameters it is actually passed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
inline constexpr bool is_any_v = (... || std::is_same_v<T, Ts>);

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_char_v = is_any_v<T, char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t>;

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_arithmetic_not_char = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && !is_char_v<T>;

template<typename A, typename B>
double sum(A a, B b) {
    if constexpr (is_arithmetic_not_char<A> && is_arithmetic_not_char<B>)
        return a + b;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(10, 65) << std::endl; // 75
    std::cout << sum(10, 'A') << std::endl; // 0
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/Jhw3qX70R)

The [`std::is_arithmetic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) trait is true only for integral types and floating point types, and false for all other types. The problem is that character types, like `char`, are also integral types. So, this code allows `sum()` to actually calculate a result only if called with arithmetic types that are not also character types, otherwise it will return 0 for everything else.

However, your question is tagged C++11 and C++14, and in those versions, [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is not available (same with [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)), but you can use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead to accomplish something similar using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_char_v = std::is_same<T,char>::value || std::is_same<T,wchar_t>::value || std::is_same<T,char16_t>::value || std::is_same<T,char32_t>::value;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_arithmetic_not_char = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !is_char_v<T>;

template<typename A, typename B, typename std::enable_if<is_arithmetic_not_char<A> && is_arithmetic_not_char<B>, int>::type = 0>
double sum(A a, B b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<typename A, typename B, typename std::enable_if<!(is_arithmetic_not_char<A> && is_arithmetic_not_char<B>), int>::type = 0>
double sum(A, B) {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(10, 65) << std::endl; // 75
    std::cout << sum(10, 'A') << std::endl; // 0
    return 0
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/8M2qKg6G0I)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Would the isdigit() function work for you?

```
char value = 'A'; 
if (isdigit(value))
   sum(10, value); 
else
   sum(0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes it works, but there is still a problem, sum function takes two double parameters, so if the value was 100 instead of 'A', the program would crash, because isdigit() works only for one char at a time.

Comment: @Mario why would it crash? 100 easily fits in a double. And passing 100 to isdigit() would simply return 0 since 100 is the value of 'd'

Comment: No, this does not work the way you think.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I mean 1000 not 100, if you pass 1000 to the function, the program would crash